# D3 Rotate Bar Chart Values by 90 Degrees

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am completely new to Java Script and D3. I'm trying to rotate the values in the bar chart by 90 degrees. However, I cannot rotate them individually. I've tried many different ways to approach this issue but have had no luck. Below is the code.

```
    const render = data => {
    const chartTitle = 'Top 10 Most Populous Countries';

    const yAxisLabel = 'Population';

    const xAxisLabel = 'Country';

    const margin = { 
            top: 100, 
            right: 50, 
            bottom: 150, 
            left: 150 
    }; 

    // Dimensions: 400 x 400 
    // used for the initial rendering 
    // width to height proportion 
    // its preserved as the chart is resized 
    const width = 1200 - margin.left - margin.right; 
    const height = 600 - margin.top - margin.bottom;


    console.log(width);
    console.log(height);

    const xValues = d => d.country;

    const yValues = d => d.population;

    const yScaleMaxValue = Math.ceil((d3.max(data, yValues)));
        console.log(yScaleMaxValue);

    const yScaleMinValue = Math.ceil((d3.min(data, yValues)));
        console.log(yScaleMinValue);


    const xScale = d3.scaleBand().
        paddingInner(0.2).
        domain(data.map(xValues)).
        range([0, width]);

    const xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale);


    const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, yScaleMaxValue])
        .range([height, 0])
        ;

    const yAxisTickFormat = number => d3.format('.3s')(number)
        .replace('G','B')
        .replace('0.00','0');

    const yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale).tickFormat(yAxisTickFormat);

    const yValuesTextFormat = number => d3.format('.3s')(number);

    const svg = d3.select('#responsivechart3'). 
        append('svg').
        attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right). 
        attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom). 
        call(responsivefy) // Call responsivefy to make the chart responsive 
            .append('g'). 
        attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`); 


        svg.selectAll('rect')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        .attr('class', 'rect')
        .attr('x', d => xScale(xValues(d)))
        .attr('y', d => yScale(yValues(d)))
        .attr('width', xScale.bandwidth())
        .attr('height', d => height - yScale(yValues(d)))
        ;


        svg.selectAll('text')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('text')
        .attr('class', 'bar-value')
        .attr('x', d => xScale(xValues(d)))
        .attr('y', d => yScale(yValues(d)))
        .text(yValues)
        .attr('transform', `rotate(-45)`);


        svg.append('g').
            call(yAxis);

        svg.append('g')
            .attr('transform', `translate(0, ${height})`) 
            .call(xAxis)
            .selectAll('text')
            .call(wrap, xScale.bandwidth());


        svg.append('text')
            .attr('class','chart-title')
            .attr('y',-50)
            .attr('x',100)
            .attr('fill', 'black')
            .text(chartTitle);

        svg.append('text')
            .attr('class','axis-label')
            .attr('y',450)
            .attr('x',400)
            .attr('fill', 'black')
            .text(xAxisLabel);


        svg.append('text')
            .attr('class','axis-label')
            .attr('y',-100)
            .attr('x',-250)
            .attr('fill', 'black')
            .text(yAxisLabel)
            .attr('transform', `rotate(-90)`);



    function responsivefy(svg) { 

        // Container is the DOM element, svg is appended. 
        // Then we measure the container and find its 
        // aspect ratio. 
        const container = d3.select(svg.node().parentNode), 
            width = parseInt(svg.style('width'), 10), 
            height = parseInt(svg.style('height'), 10), 
            aspect = width / height; 

            // Add viewBox attribute to set the value to initial size 
            // add preserveAspectRatio attribute to specify how to scale 
            // and call resize so that svg resizes on page load 
            svg.attr('viewBox', `0 0 ${width} ${height}`). 
                attr('preserveAspectRatio', 'xMinYMid'). 
                call(resize); 

            d3.select(window).on('resize.' + container.attr('id'), resize); 

        function resize() { 
            const targetWidth = parseInt(container.style('width')); 
            svg.attr('width', targetWidth); 
            svg.attr('height', Math.round(targetWidth / aspect)); 
        } 
    }



function wrap(text, width) {
  text.each(function() {
    var text = d3.select(this),
        words = text.text().split(/\s+/).reverse(),
        word,
        line = [],
        lineNumber = 0,
        lineHeight = 1.1, // ems
        y = text.attr("y"),
        dy = parseFloat(text.attr("dy")),
        tspan = text.text(null).append("tspan").attr("x", 0).attr("y", y).attr("dy", dy + "em");
    while (word = words.pop()) {
      line.push(word);
      tspan.text(line.join(" "));
      if (tspan.node().getComputedTextLength() > width+25) {
        line.pop();
        tspan.text(line.join(" "));
        line = [word];
        tspan = text
        .append("tspan")
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", y)
        .attr("dy", ++lineNumber * lineHeight + dy + "em")
        .text(word);
      }
    }
  });
}




};   


    data = d3.csv('data.csv').then(data => {
    data.forEach(d => {
      d.population = +d.population * 1000;
    });

    console.log(data);
    render(data);

});
```

Any help on this would be deeply appreciated.

Ive also attached an image.

[Rotated Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQZtf.png)

Comment: can you add [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), would really help in addressing your issue.

Comment: I don't know how to write a minimal code example. I decided to do a horizontal bar graph instead anyway. Thank you. What I am trying to do next is to format the number shown on each bar. I'm having the hardest time with that. If you or anyone else might might be able to help, please post links. Thank you.